# Post no accede al método store del controlador Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, artisan

no puedo acceder al método `Store` de mi controlador tipo resource `testController`

Con postman obtengo respuesta de todos los métodos a excepción de Store, cuando hago `post` a la dirección `http://localhost/test` obtengo el siguiente mensaje `The page has expired due to inactivity.Please refresh and try again.` y si le agrego el slash`(/)` al final de esta forma`http://localhost/test/` vuelvo a retornar al método `index`. no entiendo la verdad que estoy haciendo mal, creo que me estoy ahogando en un vaso de agua espero me puedan ayudar, a continuación dejo información adicional.

La ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::resource('test','testController');
```

Listado de rutas que tengo según `php artisan route:list`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese error es debido al _token que usa laravel para protección CSRF en los POST.
En 5.6 con poner en la vista `@csrf` ya te lo haría bien.
Para usar postman, tienes que incluir en la cabecera `X-CSRF-TOKEN` y poner el valor de la request anterior

Comment: Ok amigo gracias por la respuesta, no sabia como obtener el token pero encontré la solución en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756682/laravel-x-csfr-token-mismatch-with-postman